# Calculate with dplyr function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the mean of 'Have.you.the.garbage' by following the age group
I want to regard the 'Have.you.throwed.the.garbage." group as number and calculate 'have.you.throwed.the.garbage'*n/sum(n) depending on age group.
But when I use this code, they calculte the score by separating depening on 'Have.you.throwed.the.garbage.' group.
Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

Here is my code

```r
Taiwan %>% 
  group_by(Age, `Have.you.throwed.the.garbage.`) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(score = n*`Have.you.throwed.the.garbage.`/sum(n))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to this platform. You can provide simplified reproducible data and your expected output to make this question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're grouping by `Have.you.throwed.the.garbage.`. 
Do you just want the mean?

```
library(dplyr)

Taiwan %>% 
  group_by(Age) %>% 
  summarize(score = mean(Have.you.throwed.the.garbage.))
```